# Why can I not use xdg-open and gnome-open in Mac?

Tags: terminal, unix

I was trying to open a png file, but for some reason the xdg-open and gnome-open commands weren't working. For example:

```
-bash: gnome-open: command not found
```

Does anyone know why? I thought I could use Linux commands on Mac terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to open an image file like a *.png*, *.jpg*, etc. from Terminal in OS X, you can use `open filename.png` where *filename.png* is the actual pathname of the target image file. By default, it will open in Preview.

In Terminal, type `man open` and press enter to read the BSD General Commands Manual for the `open` command.

OS X is not Linux and Linux specific commands like `xdg-open` and `gnome-open` do not exist in
 OS X unless they've been ported by managers like Homebrew and you have installed using one of the managers like Homebrew or installed from source code by yourself, that is if you can satisfy the dependancies involved too (which is what Homebrew does for the command it ports).